# What does this javascript do?

Tags: javascript, json

I was adding recent videos gadget on my blog. In that widget i was supposed to add this line

```
<script src="/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentpostswiththumbs">
```

also, i added another script which was having the method  **showrecentpostswiththumbs** [ used in callback ]. Please let me know what does above syntax do?

**Edit**
After Lord's comment :)

Actually, my blog is hosted on *blogspot.com*. So from that point of view, if you will append */feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script* to any blog url it will generate some code. I just wanted to know what does it do? and what happens to the method which is used in *callback* parameter [ regardless of what is the definition of callback method :) ].

for eg: **http://googleblog.blogspot.com**/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script

Comment: What you've posted is HTML to include some JavaScript in a web page.  We cannot tell what code it's referencing without at least knowing your domain.  Can you post the actual JavaScript?

Comment: @Lord: :) . just append '/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script' after any blog [ i think only blogs on blogspot will work but not sure .]. For eg:- http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to tell just from what you've posted, but the parameter naming in the URL *suggests* [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

The basics of JSONP are to allow cross-domain AJAX calls by wrapping otherwise-bare JSON objects in a function call, so that the result can be executed as a script.

JSON code:

```
function getJSON(url) {
    var xhr = new XHR(url); // pseudocode
    xhr.onsuccess = callback;
    xhr.send();
}

function callback(data) {}
```

JSON response:

```
{ "items" : [1, 5, 7] }
```

Equivalent JSONP code:

```
function getJSONP(url) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url + "&callback=callback");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function callback(data) {}
```

JSONP response:

```
callback({ "items" : [1, 5, 7] })
```

**Edit**

JSONP it is.  Compare the results of the following three requests:

- http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json
- http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script
- http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentpostswiththumbs

The first returns the feed as raw JSON, the second returns it as JSONP with a default callback name, and the third returns it as JSONP using the supplied name for the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly this script returns a script containing something like this:

```
showrecentpostswiththumbs({ /* some JSON object */ });
```

The other script that has the function `showrecentpostswiththumbs`. The function is probably used to take in the JSON object and do some handling with it.

Comment: yes, _showrecentpostswiththumbs_ is using json attributes. Should i post the code of showrecentpostswiththumbs. PS: BIG code ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a script but a link to an external script file, because you are using a relative path, we cannot see the actual script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

The src attribute specifies the URL of an external script file.
In your case, js is dynamically served server side.